# How to Custom command with Custom Intent to open my Android App using Hey, Google Voice command

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-assistant

We need to open the app using google voice command. I have creating the below code to custom Intent but when i ask to Hey Google Help to My ExampleApp then app is not opening and redirect to the browser.

Currently i have implement the below link and its working using this command.

**Find ______ on ExampleApp
Look up ______ in ExampleApp**

[https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/common/get-thing#:~:text=Stay%20organized%20with%20collections%20Save%20and%20categorize%20content%20based%20on%20your%20preferences.&text=Search%20for%20content%20or%20entities,search%20feature%20in%20an%20app](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/common/get-thing#:%7E:text=Stay%20organized%20with%20collections%20Save%20and%20categorize%20content%20based%20on%20your%20preferences.&text=Search%20for%20content%20or%20entities,search%20feature%20in%20an%20app).

But I need to custom Intent with Custom Command to open my application.

Please help me if any idea.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/common/get-thing#:~:text=Stay%20organized%20with%20collections%20Save%20and%20categorize%20content%20based%20on%20your%20preferences.&text=Search%20for%20content%20or%20entities,search%20feature%20in%20an%20app](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/common/get-thing#:%7E:text=Stay%20organized%20with%20collections%20Save%20and%20categorize%20content%20based%20on%20your%20preferences.&text=Search%20for%20content%20or%20entities,search%20feature%20in%20an%20app).